# Enabling MathJax over https

Tags: feature-request, status-completed

MathOverflow (and indeed all the StackExchange sites) support https connections. However MathJax is currently broken, because the default server for the MathJax distribution doesn't support https.

There are two relatively easy solutions:

1. per [the MathJax FAQ](http://www.mathjax.org/resources/faqs/#problem-https), change the link to https://c328740.ssl.cf1.rackcdn.com/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js when the page is being loaded over https
2. have StackExchange host a copy of the MathJax scripts on a server that supports http and https, and use a scheme independent URL, as the other pieces of javascript are loaded.

(Unfortunately the MathJax CDN currently [doesn't support](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/mathjax-users/cPD_EI_lFAw/discussion) access via http and https at the same URL.)

Comment: I ran into this problem because I use the EFF's [HTTPS everywhere](https://www.eff.org/https-everywhere) extension, which attempts to force HTTPS connections where possible.

Comment: THis came also up on meta.SO some weeks ago http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/215450/ssl-breaks-tex-rendering

Comment: SE actually does not really support HTTPS right now, there is more stuff than MathJax that breaks if you force the sites to use HTTPS.

Comment: As an interim work-around, [SOUP](http://stackapps.com/questions/4486/stack-overflow-unofficial-patch) includes a client-side fix for this issue.

Comment: Note that HTTPS is not yet _fully_ supported, this will be fixed when it is.

Comment: Seems [meta-tag:status-completed] by http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/215450/ssl-breaks-tex-rendering/225923#225923 also tested and seems to work